# settimeout on hover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery's hover to clear one timeout (cleartimeout) on a set variable (timer) and then set another (settimeout) once the mouse leaves the element. Any ideas on how to do this?

My code so far (that doesn't work!!!!) is:

```
$(function () {

    $('ul.contact').hover(function () {

        $(this).clearTimeout(timer).animate({ 'opacity': 0.7 });
    }, function () {
        $(this).setTimeout(function () {
            $('ul.contact').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 8000);
        });

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('li#contact').removeClass('cur');
        $('li#$url').addClass('cur');
    }, 8625);

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

setTimeout() and clearTimeout() are functions of the (global) window object, so they should be called without an object. In your example, remove the "$(this)." before the calls to setTimeout and clearTimeout

Answer (score 4):

You also can't chain a `.animate()` call off ot the `clearTimeout()` like you're trying to.

Answer (score 2):

The hoverIntent jQuery plugin might help. It allows you to tune the sensitivity of a mouseover:

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

...which I suspect is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that I had not set another variable for the actual element I wanted to keep displayed. Have now set another variable and all works fine with the new code:

Many thanks for the tips though, they are also included!

```
$(function () {

    $('ul.contact').hover(function () {

        clearTimeout(display);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    }, function () {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        $('li#contact').removeClass('cur');
        $('li#$url').addClass('cur');
    });

});
```